# Login to nopCommerce web API via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, api, nopcommerce

I'm using nopcommerce V3.90 . in addition, I have installed the rest API plugin on the website.this is an example for using the rest API :

[REST API | V 0.1 (beta)](http://newcms.negarnameh.com/api/v1.0/Tokens)

I have tested that in postman as below:

[image]

As you see, postman gives us the access token as the response. now I'm trying to get access token via ajax as follow:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
 $("#but_submit").click(function() {

        var username1 = $("#username").val().trim();
        var password1 = $("#password").val().trim();
        alert(tt);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://newcms.negarnameh.com/api/v1.0/Tokens",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                UserNameOrEmail: username1,
                Password: password1
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function(message) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But it returns me error! in addition, I have used `JSON.stringify` as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#but_submit").click(function() {

        var username1 = $("#username").val().trim();
        var password1 = $("#password").val().trim();
        var Loginobj = {};
        Loginobj.UserNameOrEmail = username1;
        Loginobj.password = password1;
        var tt = JSON.stringify(Loginobj);
        alert(tt);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://newcms.negarnameh.com/api/v1.0/Tokens",
            type: 'POST',
            data: tt,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function(message) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But the answer is still error message!
anybody can help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check the browser console, you would find the exact issue there. The issues mostly like of CORS; when you request from one server to another, you need to allow that domain to serve the request-both the end.

However, from local machine, you can request to the server and receive the response.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var credentials = {
            UserNameOrEmail: "your_user_name",
            Password: "your_password"
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://newcms.negarnameh.com/api/v1.0/Tokens",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:"json",  
        data: credentials,  
        success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```